# Getting the outside faces of a mesh?

Tags: mesh

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYQ6V.png)<- Side of chest[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYQ6V.png)<-Neck
Can I select only the faces that are on the outside of the mesh? I just want to select all of the external faces.

Comment: Do you mean the mesh is solidified? Is it manifold or not? (are there any holes in it / areas consisting of only one side of faces etc) What does its geometry look like, is it all quads? Could you show some screenshots of the mesh in Edit mode?

Comment: @MrZak I'm pretty sure it's completely non-manifold and I am trying to just get the outside so I can 3d print it. I will add some screenshots to the original post. It's mostly quads. I would share the file but its 32 mb and honestly kind of disgusting I just threw it together.

Comment: @MrZak Just realized Google drive is a thing please tell me if there is any forseeable fix https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WNXgNJdAf5QwqHgWkjTY5oiwFYa-QQ-U